# How to find 64-bit process info using a 32-bit process

Tags: vb.net

I have a 32 bit application that shells a second application that can be 32 or 64-bit depending upon the computer it's running on.

I only want one instance of the second application to run at a time, and I need the first application to prevent the second from being launched more than once.

I want to be able to use GetProcessesByName to obtain the running processes.  This seems to work fine.  It's when I attempt to obtain the module data to find out what folder the second application was run from that things fall apart.

Does anyone have a suggestion for identifying 64-bit processes and their folder of origin from a 32-bit application?

Thank you,
SH

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be easier if you set a Mutex when launching second app.
In main app you could do this: if Mutex doesn't exist you run second app (which creates Mutex when run and release it when closing), otherwise you skip...

**EDITED**:
You can't edit second app to insert the creation of a mutex, ok.
But you can do this in **main app**:

- Create a background worker `BackgroudWorker wrk`
- Set a private bool to true: `bool running = false`
- Execute wrk when you want the new app run: `if (running) return; running = true;`
- wrk creates a Process and waits for its end
- when wrk ends `running = false`

Just an idea...

**EDITED AGAIN:**
If you close first app and reopen it, user is able to run second app again.
So you could do this:

- Create a background worker `BackgroudWorker wrk`
- Write a tmp file (on NTFS it can be empty)
- Execute wrk when you want the new app run:
   if your tmp file exists then exit;
- wrk creates a Process and waits for its end
- when wrk ends deletes tmp file

With this method, even if user quits your first app, tmp file remains on hdd; so when user runs first app again, second app will not be executed.
Remeber that if user is **smart** enough to undestand this, he could manully delete file and the trick is done.
Finally: are you sure user cannot run directly second app?

Comment: I've done this in other applications.  I don't have the ability to edit the second application.  It's all up to the first application to identify the processes and identify which (if any) of them where launched from a specific folder.

Comment: I think my solution is more safe then checking processes, because to do this you **must** be Administrator (and some process may be hidden)

Comment: I have a question about your BackgroundWorker idea.  Would this work between sessions of the first application?  Our software currently uses timers and timer events to disable the ability to run the second application from within the session.  Our problem occurs when users launch the second application, then close and reopen the first application.  Having been closed and reopened, it has no "knowledge" that the second application has been launched, so we check for it.  Thank you for your help, if this backgroundworker idea will span sessions, it's probably what we're looking for.

Comment: @Superhuman: I think the problem for multiple sessions is still present. if you close first app, when you re-open it it has running=false, so there's no way. Look at my edited post for a better solution

Comment: User can directly run the second app, but it has a password encoded into the command line, so it won't function properly unless called by the first app.

Comment: @Superhuman: oh, that sounds good :) Did you manage your app to work?

Comment: @Marco: No, I still don't have a solution.  I will be working on this today.  I think I'm going to write a program that finds whether or not the second application is running.  I will make a 64-bit and a 32-bit version, and these will write a file or leave a message in the registry.

Comment: @Superhuman: as I suggested in my re-edited post, yeah I think that writing a tmp file is the best solution... Well, you could even combine (if you wanna be paranoic... as I am often) tmp file and registry entry... Be careful where you write tmp file: do it in user dir if you want to avoid troubles with Windows Seven; the same for registry... If you're using VB.NET why you want to write two versions for 32 and 64bit? Compile for every platform and live happy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WMI API (`System.Management` namespace) for this, specifically the [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx). The example below shows to get the process id and full command line from all running notepad instances.

```
Imports System.Management

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim wmi = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ProcessId, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE ""%notepad%""")
        Dim result = wmi.Get().OfType(Of ManagementObject)()
        For Each r In result
            Console.WriteLine("Process ID: {0}, Command Line: {1}" r("ProcessId"), r("CommandLine"))
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code shown above, when running as part of a 32-bit process can obtain info from a 64-bit process?  I tried entering your code, but received syntax errors.  I'm completely unfamiliar with the WMI API.